# Flexbox still being spotty in Safari, flex-wrap not working

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I have perused the forums looking for an answer to this, but still nothing works. I am using CSS3 flexbox styling for a footer on my website. HTML is as follows:

```
<footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">

            <!-- copyright -->
            <div id="box1" class="box">
                <a class="btn" id="btn-donate" href="#">Donate</a>
                <a class="btn" id="btn-news" href="#">Get News</a>
            </div>
            <div id="box2" class="box">
                <h2>Quill Theatre</h2>
                <p>P.O. Box 7265<br>
                Richmond, VA 23221</p>
                <p>Info@QuillTheatre.org<br>
                804.340.0115</p>
                <span>Social goes here</span>

            </div>
            <div id="box3" class="box">3</div>
            <!-- /copyright -->

</footer>
```

And my CSS is as follows...its a little dirty bc Ive been trying a bunch of stuff to work:

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer .box {
  order: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: auto;
}
.footer #box2 {
  order: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  flex: 2 2 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 2 2 auto;
  -ms-flex: 2 2 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.footer #box2 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This works fine on every browser, except Safari- the wrapping does not occur. What am I missing here that would not allow for wrapping?

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: The latest version, 8.0.4. I have since adjusted my prefixes and I got everything to push to one line, but still no wrapping occurs on Safari.

Comment: I don't expect it to make a difference here since Safari is still listed as requiring prefixes, but your unprefixed properties should be last.  You're also being redundant by specifying flex-direction, flex-wrap, and flex-flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone wondering:

I had way may too much prefixing going on which was throwing off Safari's webkit. I was able to solve this issue by using proper flexbox rules (for example, using flex as shorthand and not declaring flex-grow or flex-shrink) and using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to handle vendor prefixing.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone experiencing a similar issue.**

My flex layout with an inline list was working great on Chrome but the wrap was not working on Safari.

I had a `min-width: 25%` on the `li`s. 
Once I removed that it displayed correctly on Safari.